# how to select the value of element based on where condition from repeating node in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, conditional-statements

I have requirement to use XSLT to select values from XML files of this general form:

```
<compartment>
 <receipt>
   <Measurements>
      <Measurement>
          <Identifier>temperature>/Identifier>
          <Quantity>30.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement> 
       <Measurement>
          <Identifier>density>/Identifier>
          <Quantity>30.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement> 
   </Measurements>
</receipt>
<receipt>
   <Measurements>
      <Measurement>
          <Identifier>volume>/Identifier>
          <Quantity>30.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement> 
       <Measurement>
          <Identifier>density>/Identifier>
          <Quantity>30.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement> 
   </Measurements>
</receipt>
<compartment>
```

Specifically, I want to extract the value of the <Quantity> element whose sibling <Identifier> has value "temperature". My problem is that I don't know how to select only the <receipt> that contains the temperature value (the first in the example).

I tried with this XSLT, but it does not work correctly:

```
<Output>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(compartment/receipt[Measurements/pidx:Measurement[Identifier='Temperature']/Measurements/Measurement[pidx:UnitQualifier='ProductWeight']/Quantity)"/>
</Output>
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Given the following **well-formed** input:

**XML**

```
<compartment>
  <receipt>
    <Measurements>
      <Measurement>
        <Identifier>temperature</Identifier>
        <Quantity>30.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <Identifier>density</Identifier>
        <Quantity>31.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement>
    </Measurements>
  </receipt>
  <receipt>
    <Measurements>
      <Measurement>
        <Identifier>volume</Identifier>
        <Quantity>32.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <Identifier>density</Identifier>
        <Quantity>33.0</Quantity>
      </Measurement>
    </Measurements>
  </receipt>
</compartment>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Output>
        <xsl:value-of select="compartment/receipt/Measurements/Measurement[Identifier='temperature']/Quantity"/>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Output>30.0</Output>
```

---

Note that XML is case-sensitive: `'Temperature'` is not the same thing as `'temperature'`.